# How much gas is included in transaction by default?

Tags: solidity

I am getting an out of gas error when using transaction that creates another contract using truffle, but the transaction goes through fine in the solidity online compiler. The transaction uses 994220 gas.. Does the online compiler send more gas by default?

Comment: You can see how much gas the online compiler is sending in the "transactions" pane (looks like a paper airplane). By default it is 3,000,000

Comment: It's likely that something goes wrong with the transaction itself and it manifests as "out of gas" when you submit the transaction, so no amount of gas will resolve it. Consider pasting the contract and the truffle javascript code that submits the transaction. Maybe someone will be able to spot the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there's no "official" default, and it's quite possible that there never will be, considering that implementations may pick different defaults.

It's better to send the transaction with a specific, but sufficient, amount of gas. For example, `web3.eth.sendTransaction({gas: <some large number>})` or `someContract.someMethod(arg1, arg2, {gas: <some large number>})`.